# Render entity form type

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I have a problem with rendering the entity form type from symfony2. I have a category entity and the services entities the have relationship:

**Category:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Service", mappedBy="category")
 */
private $services;
```

**Service:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="services")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $category;
```

And I need to render form that have services field like this:

```
<div class="group">
{{ all services from one category }}
</div>
<div class="group">
{{ all services from the next category }}
</div>
```

Does someone know how to do it without transfer anything except the form to a template?

Comment: You should take a look at the symfony form component, and how you can render it http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/forms.html

Comment: I've read it already. I haven't found there anything about changing rendering on the entity form type.(

Comment: When you are rendering a form, you are doing this via the $formBuilder by adding ->add('attribute', 'ClassType'), if you want your service to be rendered through the category, you will use something like $formMapper->add('services', 'entity'), but nothing is done with twig.

Comment: Please tell that you want to do.

Comment: I want to show the services from a database on a form grouped by category and these groups wrapped by divs